# How to use ImageMagick `drawtext` method in AWS Lambda function?

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, imagemagick, drawtext

I currently am running a Node 8 Lambda function using ImageMagick 7 surfaced by the Node gm module (https://github.com/aheckmann/gm) to annotate some image processing. The other ImageMagick functions (such as `resize()` or `quality()`) that I am using work correctly; however using `drawText()` does not error yet also does not result in any text being drawn on the image that is output back to s3. I haven't been able to find much information about using `drawText()` in Lambda and am curious if anyone else is successfully doing it, using Node or otherwise. Any firsthand experience or insights would be much appreciated.

I am suspicious that this has something to do with fonts (or lack thereof), and therefore have tried to add my own font of `<type name="Gotham" fullname="Gotham-Book" family="Gotham" weight="400" style="normal" stretch="normal" glyphs="/var/task/imagemagick/etc/ImageMagick-7/Gotham-Book.ttf"/>` to the ImageMagick `type.xml` file found at `etc/ImageMagick-7/type.xml`.

```
const aws = require('aws-sdk');
const im = require('gm').subClass({
    imageMagick: true,
    appPath: '/var/task/imagemagick/bin/',
});
const s3 = new aws.S3();

const IMAGEMAGICK_PATH = `${process.env.LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}/imagemagick/bin/`;
const INPUT_SOURCE_BUCKET = 'input';
const OUTPUT_SOURCE_BUCKET = 'output';

exports.handler = (event, context) => {
    process.env.PATH = `${process.env.PATH}:${IMAGEMAGICK_PATH}`;

    console.log(`** Event Received ** ${event.Records[0].Sns.Message}`);
    const message = JSON.parse(event.Records[0].Sns.Message);

    const inputKey = decodeURIComponent(message.Records[0].s3.object.key.replace(/\+/g, ' '));
    console.log(`** Image Input Key ** ${inputKey}`);

    // This splits the input key on the `/`, creates an array of strings,
    // and pulls the last string from that array.
    const filename = inputKey.split('/')[3].split('.')[0];

    let channel;
    let imageBuffer;
    let imageType;
    let outputKeyPath;
    let shootId;

    console.log('** Download beginning **');
    // Download the image from S3 into a buffer.
    const getParams = {
        Bucket: INPUT_SOURCE_BUCKET,
        Key: inputKey
    };
    s3.getObject(getParams, (err, response) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log('err :', err);
            return err;
        }
        imageBuffer = response.Body;
```

...pause to assign relevant variables & such, and then ...

```
        console.log(imageBuffer, filename);
        im(imageBuffer)
            .antialias(true)
            // Remove profile data http://aheckmann.github.io/gm/docs.html#profile.
            .noProfile()
            .resize(830)
            // Adjusts the jpeg|miff|png|tiff compression level, values
            // range from 0 to 100.
            .quality(85)
            .fill('white')
            .font('Gotham', 24)
            .drawText(4, 7, 'image text', 'SouthWest')
            .toBuffer('PNG', (err, buffer) => {
                if (err) {
                    console.error(`** error - convert - toBuffer - ${err} **`);
                    return err;
                }
                const Key = `${outputKeyPath}_full.png`;
                console.log(`** Output Path ** ${Key}`);
```

...end of the relevant bit, processed image is then sent back to s3

Comment: Is Gotham font available to ImageMagick by name? If not, try the path to the Gotham font file itself.

Comment: I'm in the same situation, using the font path instead of the name.

Comment: Any resolution on this? for us works in node 8 but not 10 or 12? AWS lambda here too.

Comment: @tesslins Did you get this sorted?  Same problem here.